# Render latex documents in javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript, latex, pdflatex

Here is the big picture of what I want to do. I need a wiki for my University where we can modify tex file. The structure is the same as a normal wiki (history, comments, etc.) except the code of the documents would be only latex.

**So I would like to know if there is a way (javascript, php) to compile a latex document online every time a modification is made ?**

*Note : I searched on google and stackoverflow and I did not find what I want yet. I do not need mathjax because I need more than just math equation. I read this solution too ([PHP - LaTeX rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408278/php-latex-rendering)) but I would prefer to do it only in php or javascript*

thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [LaTeX2HTML](http://www.latex2html.org/) for running a process server-side, and [LaTeX4Web](http://eric.chopin.pagesperso-orange.fr/latex/latex4web.htm) for doing it client side with Javascript.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116054/what-is-the-best-way-to-embed-latex-in-a-webpage) might be relevant too.

For a PHP specific project, check out http://drupal.org/project/drutex even if you aren't using Drupal. It has latex2html and html2latex functions.

Comment: thx for your answer. LateX2Html could be a solution, but I would prefer to do it only in javascript or php. The other too solution only render math formula such as $ \lambda $ and I need to render a complete document.

Comment: Yey ! Thx a lot for your time. Drutex seems a good solution. I will check this out later today.